# Limit to 10 latest rows for each value of a given column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

Assume I have the following table structure:

```
create table foo.bar(
  id serial primary key,
  nema character varying(128) not null,
  cat int not null default 0,
  _date timestamp default default current_timestamp
);
```

I fill this table every day with a lot of data, and I would just keep latest 10 records of a same cat value.
For example I have 5k rows which 100 of them have `cat` value `0xa007`, now I like to keep the latest 10 records and delete the rest 90 rows, something like following:

```
delete foo.bar f where f.cat=(x'a007'::integer) and f.id not in (
  select b.id from foo.bar b where b.cat=(x'a007'::integer)
  order by b._date desc limit 10 offset 0)
```

But above works only for one category, how may I have a query for all categories (all values)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
delete from foo.bar where id in
(
select id from 
    ( select id, rank() over (partition by cat order by _date ) ranking from foo.bar) A
    where ranking > 10
)
```